# Selenium can not find element which is obviously visible

Tags: java, css, selenium, visible

I have a Selenium code written in Java and I need to find element which is obviously visible as you can see on the screenshot. The html code comes from Google login API page.

Here is the code:

```
if(BaseSteps.elementExists(By.xpath("//*[@role=\"button\"]"), 30))
{
    System.out.println($(By.xpath("//*[@role=\"button\"]")));
    $(By.xpath("//*[@role=\"button\"]")).shouldBe(visible, ofSeconds(120)).click();
}
```

[image]

It is the button on the picture which you can see in developer tools has display:inline-block. The println() call writes

```
<div aria-disabled="false" class="U26fgb O0WRkf oG5Srb C0oVfc kHssdc M9Bg4d" data-custom-id="iPWQ6" data-id="ssJRIf" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;" jscontroller="VXdfxd" jsname="LgbsSe" jsshadow role="button" tabindex="0" displayed:false></div>
```

where at the very end is "displayed:false". I dont understand what it means. Can somebody tell me please where is the problem?

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: try isDisplay() on that web element and see if it returns false or true.

Comment: It seems that the elements that you see in the browser are being created by JavaScript and added directly to the DOM. If you are using the Selenium text based driver, it cannot see those elements as they only exist in browser's  memory, not in the HTML file. If this is the case, you have to use a driver that interacts directly with the browser.

Comment: @whbogado can you be more specific? It is a Chrome driver. I hear first time about the elements created by Javascript are not visible for Selenium. I have another tests which works with elements created by Javascript and it works. Is there any documentation about it?

Comment: @cruisepandey isDisplayed returns false. How can I fix that state. Where is it from?

Comment: @itronic1990 no error. Only element is not visible.

Comment: the webdriver can interact with elements in the DOM.  (so yes it can "see" it or anything else populated via JS)  You're going to want to use a webdriverwait with expectedcondition of "toBeClickable"...  use one of the IDs to target it.  (IDs are always best... they should be unique)

Comment: @pcalkins .shouldBe(visible, ofSeconds(120)) comes from Selenide framework and it is an implementation of wait which waits 120 seconds till the condition visible is true.  https://selenide.org/documentation.html says Assertions play role of explicit waits in Selenide. They wait for condition (visible, enabled, text("some text")) to be satisfied until timeout reached

Comment: ...but is it clickable?  ExpectedCondition of toBeClickable will check both if it's visible and if it's clickable.

Comment: @pcalkins Does it matter? The error says element is not visible.

Comment: The weird thing is that if I run `var el = querySelectorAll('div[role="button"]');` in developer tools console it returns collection of two nodes.

Comment: It's just good to check both with one expectedcondition... I think your issue here is the locator... use one of the ids instead.

Comment: yes, there's 2 because one's behind the overlay div there...

Comment: Why are there two same elements?

Comment: Because you are using not unique locator, this locator matches 2 elements.. The first invisible and the second, I guess, visible, but selenium returns the first element matching the passed locator, which is, again, invisible. SO you can't click it

Comment: There are 2 of the same elements because the attribute `role` is not always unique.  You can't assume it would be.  As @pcalkins said, it's best to target an `id` rather than `role`

Comment: I agree that ID is the best locator but there are no IDs for it. So the second one works and is clickable. Thanks to all. Good night.

Comment: In real life most elements are not located by their ID. In most cases it's a combination of tag name and class or tag name, class and some ancestor element

Comment: does `id="ssJRIf"` not work? It's right there in the screenshot

Comment: @JD2775 it is data-id attribute not id.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't see the wraparound text.  You could try with that data-id though to see what happens

Comment: use xpath //*[@data-id='ssJRIf']  (or use data-custom-id...)

Comment: It does not matter if it is xpath or css.  I am familiar with css more than xpath. The only problem is to have unique identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue here is that you are using not unique locator.
This locator matches 2 elements. The first element is invisible and the second, I guess, visible, but selenium returns the first element matching the passed locator, which is, again, invisible.
That's why you can't click it.
So, you should find unique locator for that element.

Comment: Yes that is the problem. There are two elements which match my identifier.

Comment: Can you provide an exact link to that page so I will be able to find the correct locator for that element? Or explain the scenario / flow how to get to that page?

Comment: You dont have to. The problem is fixed. Thanks.